# make a hole in that shape with round corner in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

im trying to make that shape with the interior empty but keeping the round corner when i use pathfinder (minus front)[image: the shape i wish]it make the hole but round corner disappears[image: result with no round corner]

Anyone can help me on that one? Please, and tks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your version of Illustrator, you may need to go to "Object > Expand Appearance" before applying the Pathfinder.

Alternatively once the path is expanded you can go to "Object > Compound Path > Make" rather than Pathfinder.

Comment: I answered the same, so I'll just comment here, for additional info...: >>You make the rounded rectangle a REAL rounded rectangle, not just a rectangle with rounded EFFECTS.

In that case, use any of the ones below on the rounded rectangle:
1)MENU Object> Expand Appearance 2)MENU Object> Flatten Transparency

Taddaa!

Comment: Nice! tks a lot repeat to urself; use expand object. use expand object ;) tks again

Comment: @Makamik if this answered your question, please be certain to tick the check mark on the left side to mark it correct and give ispaany credit for it.

Comment: Done, did not know about that tks ;)